# Matlab function adapt() doesn't seem to work

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I have the following code implemented in Matlab. I want to train the perceptron using a batch algorithm to separate this liniar separable points. So, in order to do that I use adapt() function but it doesn't seem to work. What I mean by that is that my perceptron is not able to classify the points as they should be. It has some weights which are not useful in any way. On the other hand, when I use train() function everything goes according to plan.The perceptron is able to classify the points with accuracy. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

```
function problema2_1()

p = -1 + ( 1 + 1) .* rand(3,5);
for i = 1 : length(p)
    if 2 * p(1,i) - p(2,i) + p(3,i) < 0
        t(i) = -1;
    else
        t(i) = 1;
    end
end

net = newp([-1 1; -1 1; -1 1],1,'hardlims');
net.adaptParam.passes = 1000000;
net = adapt(net,p,t);


plotpv(p,hardlim(t));
hold on
plotpc(net.IW{1,1,1},net.b{1});
t - sim(net,p)
end
```

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work"? Can you post the error, actual output, and expected output in the question?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which version of matlab you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adapt` only runs passes through your training data once and thus makes very small updates to the network weights. Meanwhile `train` iterates on the training data several times until a stopping condition is met.

The examples in the [Matlab documentation for `adapt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/adapt.html) should provide some clarification. I suspect your line `net.adaptParam.passes = 1000000` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

As an immediate fix, just try looping over your `net = adapt(net,p,t)` several times to verify that the resultant network seems to be converging to the one obtained when using `train()`.